# prevent jQuery animation from moving rest of page content

Tags: jquery

i am currently working on a website, and i want an image's height and width to increase when the user hovers over it.

here is my code from http://jsfiddle.net/amoeba/KdwwL/ for the desired output.

HTML:

```
<img id="img-shadow" align="center" src="https://i2.sndcdn.com/artworks-000049446949-mwzm8s-t500x500.jpg?9d68d37" />
```

CSS:

```
#img-shadow {
    height:550px;
    width:550px;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 10px black;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img-shadow').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'width: '565px',
            'height' : '565px',
            'left' : '45px',
            'top' : '45px'
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'width' : '550px',
            'height' : '550px',
            'left' : '50px',
            'top' : '50px'
        }, 360);
    });
});
```

this is the exact effect that i want, but the problem is when i hover over the image, it affects the rest of the pages content, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/amoeba/Vwxev/

how can i get the same effect without moving content below the animated image?

**NOTE: in the second example i have the `position:absolute` property removed. on my webpage, it appears to scale outwards if i have `text-align:center`. i have the `text-align:center` property removed because jsfiddle wont center it for me and i just want to show how it moves content downward when i dont want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer 1

This is using the absolute positioning property.

I'm almost sure this is what you want. In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejP5/) I added absolute position properties so that the text doesn't move. If you want the image to be on top when the animation takes effect you can edit the z-index.

I wrapped your image in #imgdiv and your text in #otherdiv and applied this css:

```
#imgdiv {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#otherdiv {
 position: absolute;
 top: 550px;
 left: 0;
}
```

---

## Answer 2

This uses a negative margin effect of the same size of the difference of in size of the image.

Here I just added these lines of code to the hover in and hover out functions respectively.

Hover in:

```
$('#text').stop().animate({
    'margin-top': '-15px'
}, 300);
```

Hover out:

```
 $('#text').stop().animate({
    'margin-top': '0px'
}, 360);
```

I almost forgot the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHZVW/).

Comment: this seems to work but i think i have a problem somewhere in my divs, the image appears outside of my body div, which is 50% wide i believe. ill try to work with it some.

Comment: your solution does work, but not in my case. i set the position to absolute in both text and image, but the image does not want to stay in my body div, even if i adjust the z-index. thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, well. It won't stay in your body, it is now placed relative to the entire web page (that's what it means to have absolute position).  You will need to match the position by hand, editing the top, left values.

Comment: Another alternative is: add a negative margin effect to the text. I'll try it and put it in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

This might not work, and I can't test it, because my computer hates jQuery for some reason, but try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img-shadow').hover(function() {
        $('#img-shadow').stop().animate({
            'width: '565px',
            'height' : '565px',
            'left' : '45px',
            'top' : '45px'
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('#img-shadow').stop().animate({
            'width' : '550px',
            'height' : '550px',
            'left' : '50px',
            'top' : '50px'
        }, 360);
    });
});
```

Sorry if this doesn't work.

Comment: selecting "this" is the same as selecting "#img-shadow" so it basically has the same effect.